# Trouble getting json_encode array elements into seperate jQuery variables

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a PHP file which I post to using jQuery. The PHP file returns

```
$array = array('v1' => $v1, 'v2' => $v2, 'v3' => $v3);
echo json_encode($array);
```

I can read the entire returned contents to a text box using

```
$.post( "Processor.php", { var1: var1})
    .done(function( data ) {
    $("#textbox").val(data);
});
```

But I want to seperate the three array elements returned into separate jQuery variables. I have tried both of these but they dont work.

```
$("#textbox").val(data['v1']);
$("#textbox").val(data.v1);
```

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ajax post request returns a string.

You need to have it parsed :

```
$.post( "Processor.php", { var1: var1})
    .done(function( data ) {
        object = JSON.parse(data);
        $("#textbox").val(object.v1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) you should explicitly set the `dataType` to JSON:

```
$.post( "Processor.php", { var1: var1})
    .done(function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
}, 'json');
```

or send the right HTTP headers: `Content-Type: application/json`

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code as following..

```
$.getJSON("Processor.php",{ var1: var1},function(data){
     $( "#textbox" ).val( data.v1 );
     });
```

Similarly you can get other key values too from your array.